# Apache Camel adapt() method removed in version 4

Tags: java, apache-camel

While migrating from Apache Camel 3 to version 4, I've ran into the fact that method adapt() was removed from the camel context and it's no longer possible to adapt into the ModelCamelContext

```
ModelCamelContext modelContext = context.adapt(ModelCamelContext.class);        
RouteDefinition route = modelContext.getRouteDefinition(routeId);
```

The  [official migration guide](https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-4-migration-guide.html) only mentions that

> Replaced adapt() from org.apache.camel.CamelContext with getCamelContextExtension

But sadly does not elaborate on how the APIs are compatible. I'm struggling with a use case where I need to dynamically manipulate route definitions, which was fairly simple with the old ModelCamelContext approach. **I need to get route definition**, remove it from context, add different one again and manipulate outputs (getOutputs method) on it.

Any ideas how this could be achieved in Apache Camel version 4?

Comment: Please show the code of what you did in Camel 3 which you can no longer do in Camel 4. That might help people to understand what you're trying to do and provide an alternative.

Comment: Hi Mark, well in general I need to access RouteDefinition for a given routeId. This used to be a trivial task, is it not possible anymore for some reason? Posting the whole code of the testing framework is not practical in this case.

Comment: I don't use Camel, so I can't comment to the specifics, but illustrating your question with what you're doing usually goes a long way towards getting an answer.

Comment: Agree with Mark.. more information! In my case, I used `adapt` to advice a Route by first getting the RouteDefinition from the context.. In the process of upgrading to Camel4-M3 I got rid of both the adapt() call and the call to get the RouteDefinition instead passing the `routeId` parameter directly to `AdviceWith.adviceWith`.

Comment: I found you can still access `RouteDefinition` by _routeId_ by doing as follows (Kotlin):

`
val routeDefinition = (camelContext as ModelCamelContext).getRouteDefinition(routeId)
`

Comment: @JanM did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Camel migration guide https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-4-migration-guide.html
mentions following piece of migration code:

```
Removed getExtension from the interface CamelContext

Use getCamelContextExtension instead. For example ManagedCamelContext managed = context.getCamelContextExtension().getContextPlugin(ManagedCamelContext.class);
```

Based on that we were able to get the model extension via:

```
var model = context.getCamelContextExtension().getContextPlugin(Model.class);
```